# Python setproctitle + numpy truncates title at 11 characters in Linux

Tags: python

When uses numpy + setproctitle, titles are truncated to 11 characters. Any ideas why is happening that?

```
from setproctitle import setproctitle
import numpy
setproctitle("ETL-1234567890123456789")
# It's truncated to "ETL-1234567"
```

If I remove numpy import it works.

It works fine on OSX but not in Ubuntu 14.04

My numpy version 1.9.0

Comment: I think 11 characters would be te maximum amount for setting a process title on Ubuntu.

Comment: No it was numpy... I'm going to update the question

Comment: The platform is almost certainly still important, since `setproctitle` has at least a half dozen different implementations for different platforms; don't remove that from the question.

Comment: Another question: where does the truncated version show up? Because from what I can tell, on linux 2.6.9+, `setproctitle` calls `prctl` as well as clobbering `argv`, which only accepts 16 bytes (and that includes the fixed prefix and the null terminator), so it's possible that tools that look in `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/comm` will see a truncated name. (In fact, the call with a longer name in `setproctitle` should raise `ERANGE`, but it looks like you only get that from `pthread_setname_np`; `prctl` just silently copies an un-terminated buffer…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs say, [`setproctitle`](https://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/) wraps up [source code from Postgres](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ps__status_8c_source.html) that does different things on each platform.

On OS X, like most *BSD systems, just reassigning `argv[0]` to a pointer another string is sufficient.* But on Linux, it's not; you have to leave `argv[0]` pointing to the same place, and clobber that buffer (possibly rearranging the other arguments and even the environment to make space).**

<sub>* Well, not quite; you also have to change `_NSGetArgv()` and `_NSGetEnviron()`.</sub>

<sub>** How does this not screw up the rest of your code that might want to access `argv` or `env`? It makes a deep copy, then reassigns your globals so the rest of your code will see that copy; only the OS sees the original buffer.</sub>

According to the comments, this has to be done "early in startup".* Touching `sys.argv` or `sys.environ` from Python shouldn't actually matter, because those operate on copies, but NumPy is written in C, and does all kinds of stuff when it's imported that could conceivably be a problem.**

<sub>* Presumably this is because other code might either keep references to arguments or env variables that are about to be clobbered, or might call functions like `setenv` that might themselves copy the data to a new buffer so we don't end up operating on the one the OS sees.</sub>

<sub>** It's even possible that the problem is just that NumPy imports `sys` or another stdlib module, and *that's* what causes the problem.</sub>

---

So, I think the answer is to make sure you call `setproctitle` before importing `numpy`—or, to be safe, *any* C extension modules (maybe even some of the ones in the stdlib). In other words:

```
from setproctitle import setproctitle
setproctitle("ETL-1234567890123456789")
import numpy
```

Alternatively, it *may* be sufficient to delay the *import* of `setproctitle` until right before you call it:*

```
import numpy
from setproctitle import setproctitle
setproctitle("ETL-1234567890123456789")
```

<sub>* [The module init](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle/blob/master/src/setproctitle.c#L105) calls [`spt_setup`](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle/blob/master/src/spt_setup.c), which does all the horrible hackery needed to find the real `argv` buffer. So, most likely, it's too late to do this after importing NumPy. But possibly, it's OK to do it, and the problem is only problem is the results changing before you use them.</sub>

But either way, don't do anything between the import and the call.

(If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll research further and/or delete the answer.)

Comment: Thanks! The first options works well, but the second doesn't. I've an application that launch lots of process and setproctitle is called from lots of modules. What I've done is place `from setproctitle import setproctitle` at the top of each module and It works really well.

Comment: @alasarr: OK, I guess the key is to get the `spt_setup` code run as easy as possible, so as long as one of the modules with the `from setproctitle import setproctitle` gets imported early enough everything's fine… I suspected it was one or the other, but had no idea which…